# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException'

Tags: .net, c++

I created a BeginInvoke so I could write to a text box from a non-UI thread.  Thread A calls a delegate which runs testFunc in thread A's context.  testFunc then does a BeginInvoke which runs the empty function ControlBoxDelegateMethod.  If the BeginInvoke line is removed, the program runs.  But if it is left in, I get the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.

```
        private:
        //delegate void ControlBoxDelegate(Label^ myControl,int whichControl);
        void ControlBoxDelegateMethod(Label^ myControl,int whichControl)
        {
         //  myControl->Text = "Test!!!!!!!";
        }
        public: 

        void testFunc()
        {
            int which = 3;
            local_long_textBox->BeginInvoke(gcnew  ControlBoxDelegate
                           (this,&Form1::ControlBoxDelegateMethod),which);
        }
```

Could anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ControlBoxDelegateMethod` takes two parameters (a `Label^` and an `int`), but you're only passing one (an `int` named `which`). You're missing the first parameter.

So, it should probably go like this:

```
local_long_textBox->BeginInvoke(gcnew ControlBoxDelegate(this,&Form1::ControlBoxDelegateMethod), your_label, which);
```